# Process builder and flow resulting in recursion

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, visual-flows, recursion

Currently, in the process builder if you create a process and invoke a flow that will update multiple records for the same object, the process is again triggered for the records it updates, since the records getting updated also satisifies the process criteria it again invokes the same process resulting in a loop.
Let me know how i can stop recurssion here in PB.

This is my specific scenario where specific field say Tracker change in A, I need to query A and B and update a tracker on A and B.
Likewise if I change Tracker in B i need to query A and B and update tracker in A and B.

Object A - Based on TrackerName query A,B
Object B - Based on TrackerName query A,B

The above scenario will reslut in recurssion. Please suggest any way of achieving this without recurssion.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the setting Allow records to be evaluated multiple times enabled in the process builder. It does have functional implications as well if you disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Process Builder to use a specific criteria, and enable the advanced option to evaluate the record when the conditions are met. The process will call the flow, the flow will call the process, and because the conditions are still met, it won't execute the actions again. Alternatively, you can check to see if the record actually changed (in the flow), and avoid updating it if the data has not changed (use a Decision to determine if the record should be updated).